# Cannot spy on Titanium.Network methods with Jasmine

Tags: testing, jasmine, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, spying

I'm using Jasmine to write tests for a Titanium project. I have a custom util js to provide me information about the network availability.

In this util there is a helper method calling `Titanium.Network.getNetworkType()` to retrieve the current active network type. The action I do depends on the network type retrieved by this call. To ensure test coverage on this, I'm writing Jasmine tests. But unfortunately I'm having issues with spying on `Titanium.Network.getNetworkType()`

**Code snippet**:

```
console.log(Titanium.Network.getNetworkType()); // returns 1

spyOn(Titanium.Network, 'getNetworkType').andReturn(666);

console.log(Titanium.Network.getNetworkType()); // returns 1
```

Spying on a method of Titanium (e.g. getApiName()) **does** work. Any ideas on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide some more context? For example the Jasmine framework (like [this one](https://github.com/guilhermechapiewski/titanium-jasmine)) you are using?